# Loop over a cell array if file exists in folder and print to new document

Tags: matlab, for-loop, exists, cell-array

I want to loop over a cell array while reading in files within a working
folder. If that file exists, create and open new file called testcase.txt
print statement. If that file doesn't exist in working folder, do nothing
and move on to next iteration.

Here's what example looks like with search for one file

```
fid=fopen('testcase.txt','w');

if exists('abc.txt','file')
    abc.txt = 1;
    fprintf('test case successful');
else
    abc.txt = 0;
end

fclose(fid);
```

Here's a cell array example expanded over multiple cases looks like
I can't seem to get it to run properly. Can someone help me to get this
loop to work?

```
extension = {'abc.txt' 'def.txt' 'ght.txt'};
convertedfile = [abc.txt def.txt ght.txt];

fid=fopen('testcase.txt','w');

for i = extension
    if exist(['''' convertedfile ''''],'file')
        i = 1;
        fprintf('test case successful');
    else
        i = 0;
    end
end

fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
extension = {'abc.txt' 'def.txt' 'ght.txt'};
% convertedfile = [abc.txt def.txt ght.txt];

fid=fopen('testcase.txt','w');

for i = 1:length(extension)
    if ~exist(extension{i},'file')

        fprintf(fid,'test case successful\n');
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```

Also, you could print the text file for which it was successful using:

```
fprintf(fid,'%s: test case successful\n',extension{i});
```